# Dynamics 365 (online) in Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, power-automate

In Power BI there is a connection called Dynamics 365 (online) which allows me to access data entities in d365 Finance and operation.

Is it possible to access or use the same connection in Power Automate?

Comment: Sorry but your question is somewhat vague. If you’re asking if you can use the EXACT connection that’s setup in PBi, the answer is a resounding NO. If you want to use D365 in PowerAutomate with the same credentials, the answer is PROBABLY, have you even tried?!!

Answer (score 0):

yes, there's an option to connect to Dynamics 365 from Power Automate using native connectors.

The connector you are looking for is "Microsoft Dataverse" to connect to Dynamics 365.

[image]

Dynamics 365 connector has been deprecated and cannot be used for new flows since April 29, 2022.